# Red Outline in Font

Tags: css, fonts

I have the following picture which shows a screen capture of my font on the right compared to Nike's font on the left. I have perfected applied every css style that I could find in firebug and I still can't get rid of this annoying red outline. Does anyone have any idea what it is? I tried text-shadow but did not get rid of the red outline. (Image is zoomed up)

This is driving me up the wall, any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Getting rid of red outline]

Corresponding CSS

```
font-family: "TradeGothicLT-BoldCondTwenty",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif !important;
color: #333;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: normal !important;
word-spacing: -0.05em;
letter-spacing: -0.045em;
text-shadow:none;
```

Original Font: http://www.nike.com/us/en_us/c/basketball/nike-basketball-hyperdunk-plus 
Search 'Track your game' to find sample font on above page.

Thanks again

Comment: Can we see your page with the html and css?

Comment: Unfortunately, everything is on my local machine right now.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you're browsing on a webkit browser. Try adding `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialised;` to your body or html elements.

Comment: You sir are a god. Thanks a lot. Will mark as answer as soon as it's available.

Answer (score 1):

There is no red outline in the screenshot, just colored pixels. This is an example of subpixel rendering, i.e. advanced font smoothing, which is under the control of a browser, possibly settable by the user. The nonstandard CSS property mentioned in JOPLOmacedo’s answer affects WebKIT browsers only. On IE, for example, this behavior depends on settings at Windows level (and on IE settings, in older versions).

As a rule, the browser and its user should be expected to be better informed than an author about the adequacy of font smoothing, which depends on properties of the display device, among other things.